# t-sql: What is the best way to compare against decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my `query` I need to get records where percentage is less then 50%.

The field that stores percentage values are defined as `char(3)`.
For example, I see some data defined as '.35'

In my query I used a condition `where mypercentagevalue < '.50'`, but it will not work as I noticed that the field also has values such as '85', '95', '90' and etc

Would can I use to compare against all cases

Thank you

Comment: You need to get your data consistent FIRST...

Comment: This data already exist unfortunately and I have to deal with that now.

Comment: The best way to deal with it will be to fix it. Pick a format and make it consistent.  If you aren't able to either make a new table with corrected formatting or fix the current data to make it consistent then you have larger issues.

Comment: hard to know if this will provide the most accurate results without knowing all of the formats the numbers will apepar in. if it is always .XX, then your method should work.

Answer (score 0):

Eugene - since this field is defined as char(3), do the following:

first - make sure you have a number in the field with a case statement and the IsNumeric function.  Then cast it to a number.

```
select * from [dbo].[YourTable]
where cast(case isnumeric([YourField]) when 0 then 0 else [YourField] end as numeric(9,2)) < .5
```

Whole numbers (85,90, etc...) will show up in the results until you get your data formatted correctly.

Comment: Yes, because `£` casts to `numeric` so easily. `ISNUMERIC` is a *fundamentally* useless function because it answers a question nobody wants to ask. It doesn't tell you whether a string can be cast to a *specific* data type.

Comment: What about data such as '.35'?

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm getting the following error when trying to run your example: 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.35' to data type int.'

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Eugene.it and @JNK but if for some reason (and I can't think of a good one) you can't fix the data then you could use something like below.

```
WHERE .5 > CASE WHEN CAST(mypercentagevalue as decimal (6,2)) >= 1 THEN CAST(mypercentagevalue as decimal (6,2))/100 ELSE CAST(mypercentagevalue as decimal (6,2)) END
```

I would do something like the following though.

```
UPDATE #temp
SET mypercentagevalue = CASE WHEN CAST(mypercentagevalue as decimal (6,2)) >= 1 THEN
                                  CAST(mypercentagevalue as decimal (6,2))/100 
                                  ELSE CAST(mypercentagevalue as decimal (6,2)) END
```

Comment: when doing the first query, I'm getting 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric'

Comment: That means you have data that isn't numeric.  See @bsivel's answer to check for that.  That means your data is messed up even more than having a 90 in there.  You really need to fix the data because your query will never return complete data with wrong values in that field.  Try SELECT * FROM ??? WHERE ISNUMERIC(mypercentagevalue) = 0

Comment: Again, checking the return value of `ISNUMERIC` isn't a guarantee because it doesn't answer the question you think it does. `ISNUMERIC('1d1')`  returns `1` and yet you cannot convert that string to a `decimal(6,2)`

Comment: Understand.  Then what would you suggest to find the non-numeric data.

Comment: If you're expecting only a few patterns, then `LIKE` expressions are more likely to be reliable.

Comment: Damien - I was aware that isnumeric('$1') would return true but not '1d1'.  Are there other undocumented characters that are like this?